# Does my JavaScript get called when page is resized during print process?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a some simple HTML with a call to the [TextFill](http://jquery-textfill.github.io/) jQuery library to auto-fit some text to the available space in my layout.

The layout is fine when on-screen, but when printed out it appears the page is resized and the JavaScript needs to be re-executed accordingly.

Can I rely on $(window).resize() to be called when this happens?

Interestingly the body width is fixed at 700px, but it still seems to be being resized?

The div for the text is set to 50%, and I have two of these divs next to eachother:

```
<div style="display:table; width:100%; border:1px solid black; border-right:none; border-bottom:none;">
    <div style="display:table-row;">
        <div style="display:table-cell; border:1px solid black; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:20px; text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom;" class="td_two_by_two">
            <div class="text_two_by_two text" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                <span style="font-size: 47px;">some pockets</span>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-bottom:10px; display:inline-block;" class="image_two_by_two">
                <img style="width:100%; max-height:100%; margin:auto; display:block;" src="some_pockets.jpg">
            </div>
            <div style="border-bottom:solid 1px black;" class="write_two_by_two">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell; border:1px solid black; border-left:none; border-top:none; padding:20px; text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom;" class="td_two_by_two">
            <div class="text_two_by_two text" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                <span style="font-size: 46px;">some earrings</span>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-bottom:10px; display:inline-block;" class="image_two_by_two">
                <img style="width:100%; max-height:100%; margin:auto; display:block;" src="some_earrings.jpg">
            </div>
            <div style="border-bottom:solid 1px black;" class="write_two_by_two">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.td_two_by_two {
    width:50%;
}

.text_two_by_two {
    height:100px;
}

.image_two_by_two {
    height:180px;
}

.write_two_by_two {
    height:50px;
}
```

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').imagesLoaded(function() {
        $('.text').textfill({maxFontPixels:100, changeLineHeight:true});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is no...

You really should rely on CSS for your print to work the way you want it to. I do not have a great answer as to the WHY it doesn't, but we do know CSS works so please attempt to rely on that. It is possible that you may find a full CSS solution to your site as well.

use

```
<link href="/css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
```